# Firemonkey iOS CFBundleExecutable error deploying application

Tags: ios, delphi, deployment, firemonkey

For the last 48 hours I'm trying to deploy my application to my iPhone.
I'm getting an error

```
unable to extract application bundle executable info. Please check Info.plist CFBundleExecutable key
```

Did anybody face the same problem? I haven’t changed the provisioning profiles or any versioninformations, the error occurred out of nowhere.

My Workspace set up:

- Delphi Rio 10.3.1
- macOS HighSierra
- iOS 12.1
- latest XCode build

Things I'v ealready tried:

- changing CFBundleidentifier to blank or "????", right now it is com.jilsApp.* in the version information
- rename the Project
- deploying another project to the iPhone successfull and reading the info.plist file
- changing the info.plist of my project by hand
- replacing "$ModuleName" with projectname within the version information
- rebooting mac and iPhone
- restart PAServer20.0
- and finally asking Dr. Google

Comment: Needs more info, e.g. what value is in CFBundleIdentifier in the Version Info in the Project Options? Does the project name have any "non-standard" characters? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleidentifier?language=objc

Comment: hello @DaveNottage my projectname is "ReTinAClient" so nothing complicated like I mentioned before, I was able to deploy the application to my iPhone serveral times and out of nowhere I get the error. I edited my original post to provide more information about my workspace set up and things I'vre tried.

Comment: Have you checked your sources against older versions? Especially the .dproj and .deployproj might have gotten some kink along the way. Also try to deploy a version built with an older version of your sources i.e. one you know worked.

Comment: good idea, I can have a look into my github and check the info.plist and I can also check the files you‘ve mentioned

Comment: @LarsP Any news on the subject?

Comment: Not yet but I found a Delphi thread. The recommended solution I’ll try this afternoon. https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=660810

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well, kind of an answer...
Nothing worked so far, so I decided to create a new project, added all forms, units and resources, build successfully and deployed to my iPhone without any problem. Insteat of wasting more time trying to fix the problem, I only spend 15 minutes to set up a iOS project.